# password change script in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Help please with this password change script

here's mys html code

```
<form method="POST" action="pass.php">

Current Password:
<input type="password" name='password'/>

New Password
<input type="password" id="password1" name="password1"/>

Retype New Password:</td>
<input type="password" id="password2" name="password2"/>

<input type="submit" value="Change Password">   

 </form>
```

here's my php script for change password. it's working fine but when i try to login the new password it is always incorrect.

```
              $userData = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              $hash = hash('sha256',$userData['salt'].hash('sha256',$password));

                  if ($hash == $userData['password']) {

                        $hash1 = hash('sha256', $password1);
                        function createSalt()
                        {
                            $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
                            RETURN substr($text, 0, 3);
                        }
                        $salt = createSalt();
                        $pass = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash1);


                        $qry = $handler->prepare( "UPDATE login SET password = ? WHERE id = ?" );
                        $qry->execute(array($pass,$id));  
                        $error = 'Password successfully changed! The system will now log you out. Please login again.';
                        session_destroy();
                        header('refresh:5; url=/../lab/login.php');            
                  }else{
                    $error = 'Incorrect Password.';
                  }
```

Here's my login script for reference.

```
<?php
$errors = array();
if ($email&&$pass){
$qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT `email` FROM login WHERE `email` = ?" );
$qry->bindValue( 1, $email );
$qry->execute();
$row = $qry->rowCount();

  if ($row == 1){
    $qry = $handler->prepare( "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = ? AND stat = '1'" );
    $qry->bindValue( 1, $email );
    $qry->execute();
    $row = $qry->rowCount();
        if ($row == '1'){ 
        $userData = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $hash = hash('sha256',$userData['salt'].hash('sha256',$pass));


          if($hash == $userData['password']){
            $_SESSION['email']=$email;
            header('Location:/../lab/profile.php');
          }
          else{
            $errors = "<center>The Password/Email you Entered is incorrect. Please check your login Details and <br><a href='/../lab/login.php' style='font-size:12px;text-decoration:underline;'>Login Again</a></center> ";
          }
        } 

        else{
          $errors = "Your Account is not yet activated. Please check your email."; 
        }
   }
  else{
    $errors = "<center>The Password/Email you Entered is incorrect. Please check your login Details and <br><a href='/../lab/login.php' style='font-size:12px;text-decoration:underline;'>Login Again</a></center>";
  }
}

else{
  $errors = "Please fill in the Email and Password fields to login";
 }
?>
```

Everything is working. It's just when I try to change password and then login the new password, the system returns incorrect password. maybe there's some problem with encrypting the new password.

Thanks

Comment: Can you log in with your old password? Check the value of $password1. You might be hashing a null value.

Comment: I cannot login with the old password also with the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the full php script?
There are many ways to debug this.

- Try to echo `$_POST['password1'];` maybe it doesn't have a value.
- did you try `$hash1 =    hash('sha256', $_POST['password1']);`?
- or maybe you forgot to hash the `$pass` in `if ($email&&$pass)`

From what I saw on your code. Listed above is the most critical reason of your problem.